# URL-Rewriting: Rules work for some .php pages, but not for others.

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an `.HTACCESS` file which allows a user to write the `username` of a user, on my social networking site in the URL.

I first implemented these rules to easily access specific users `profile_page`'s by just modifying the URL, i.e. `profile_page/freddy` - Will take me to Freddy's profile page etc. And the rules were working.

I also have `bio.php` which is unique for each user. Therefore, I have written the exact same rules as I did for `profile_page` but just changed the file name. However, this does not work, I get an 404 error.

I have several pages similar to this, but the rules for `profile_page` are the only ones that work.

**.HTACCESS in full:**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ profile_page.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^profile(?:_page)?/([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ photos.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^photos?/([\w-]+)/?$ photos.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ photos.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ hearted_thoughts.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule hearted_thoughts([\w-]+)/?$ hearted_thoughts?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ hearted_thoughts?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ favourited.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule favourited([\w-]+)/?$ favourited?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ favourited?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ bio.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule bio([\w-]+)/?$ bio?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ bio?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewriteRules are conflicting with one another because of the indentical rewrite patterns ( 
`^(me)?/?$`
 and 
`^([w-]+)$` 
) in all rules.

edit your rules like this :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#--let existent files and dir pass untouched--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
################  
#--rewrite /me to /profile_page.php--
RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ profile_page.php [L,NC]
###############
#--Rewrite /profile/foo to /profile_page.php?u=foo--#
RewriteRule ^profile(?:_page)?/([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
###############
#--rewrite /bio/foo to /bio.php?u=foo--#
RewriteRule ^bio/(.+)$ /bio.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
###############
#--other rules--#
```